An object always less than an arbitrary number in Python 3, similar to None in Python 2?
In Python 2, None type is considered smaller than anything, so for any arbitrary number x we have:
>>>  None < x
True

Is there anything that behaves similarly for Python 3, as this was removed/fixed? Given an arbitrary number in Python 3, is there an object type that is always considered smaller than x?

There's always negative infinity.

Why do you ask? (Yes, context matters! Does it have to be “built-in” in some sense? What counts as a number (-inf, nan, complex, …)?)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"In Python 2, None type is considered smaller than anything" Damn that was a bad idea...

do you means float('-inf') < x?

Assuming you only mean the domain of Real numbers, since complex numbers don't really have ordering and hence no smallest complex number, you can use -math.inf
import math

assert -math.inf < 5
assert -math.inf < 0
assert -math.inf < -5
assert -math.inf < -6648768467366434834687349384937894738473493

Note: Don't forget to add the negative sign in front. It becomes positive infinity if not.

I think this will be as good we we can get without making your own class. Just be sure not to compare with -math.inf or math.nan

@mattmess1221 If you're willing to check not x >= y instead of x < y, you can do a little better in the sense that you can cover y = -inf as well.
